# Contact Details coming improper order

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to access the Contact Details of all contacts in the Emulator.I got the desired solution for the accessing of other details.There is an issue when access the phone and email type.I used below code to get the Phone Type and Email Type.The application is running with no compile errors.

**complete code**

```
public class GetAllDatas extends Activity {

ListView lvItem;
private Button btnAdd;
String Ptype, Etype;
int contactPhoneType;

String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.lvitems); 
    btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);

    itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist); 
    lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            readContacts();
        }
    });

} 

private void readContacts()
{
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);


    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        displayName  = "" ;
        ArrayList<String> phoneNumber  = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> emailAddress  = new ArrayList<String>();

        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        /*                   Email                   */ 

        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        {
            emailAddress.add(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))); 

             int contactPhoneType = emails.getInt(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));



             switch(contactPhoneType){
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME: 
                     Etype = "Home";
                     break; 
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK: 
                    Etype = "Work";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_MOBILE: 
                    Etype = "Mobile";

                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_OTHER: 
                    Etype = "Other";
                    break;
           }                  
       }



        emails.close(); 


      /*            Phone Number and Type   */ 

        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                 phoneNumber.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))); 

                  contactPhoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));


                 switch(contactPhoneType){
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME: 
                         Ptype = "Home";
                         break; 
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK: 
                        Ptype = "Work";
                        break; 
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:  
                        Ptype = "Mobile";
                        break; 
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER: 
                        Ptype = "Other";
                        break;
               }                  
           }  



            pCur.close();  
        }   

int phoneNumberCount = phoneNumber.size();
int emailCount = emailAddress.size();

// Add arraylist data to contactlist..

if(phoneNumberCount > emailCount) {

    for (int i=0; i<phoneNumberCount; i++)
      {
        if(emailCount>i)
          {
           contactlist.add(displayName +  " , " +  Ptype + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i) + " , " + Etype + " , " + emailAddress.get(i) + "\n");    
           }
        else
        {
          contactlist.add(displayName + " , " +  Ptype + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i) + " , " + " , " + "\n");
        } 
       }
    }
    else  
       {
        for (int i=0; i<emailCount; i++) 
         {
        if(phoneNumberCount>i)
          {
            contactlist.add(displayName + " , " + Ptype + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i) + " , " +  Etype + " , " + emailAddress.get(i) + "\n"); 
          }
        else
        { 
          contactlist.add(displayName + " , " + " , " + " , " + Etype + " , " + emailAddress.get(i) +  "\n");
        }
      }
    }      
    }
    Collections.sort(contactlist);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close(); 
} 
 }
```

The Issue was, I have got the Phone Type and Email Type in the ListView of Improper order. That means I saved 2 numbers **[Home, Mobile]** and 2 emails **[Home, Work]** to a particular contact.When I run the code the ListView display for this contact became for numbers **[Mobile, Work]** and for emails **[Mobile, Work]**. I can't correct the code.How to make the ListView display proper.Anybody knows how to Debug it ?

Comment: I don't understand.... are the numbers incorrect?  Is the Mobile number being displayed for the work number?  Or are they correct and you just want them to display in a different order?

Comment: Actually the display includes 5 details... Name, NumberType, Number, EmailTYpe, Email...that means the number type means the personel number or home number or mobile ...email type is also same like this....it comes in improper order ..here is an image that I saved 2 Numbers and 2 Emails to contact KARTHIK--- first number type is home second number type Mobile and first Email type Home and 2 Work but it display as Mobile and Work for both phone and Email( http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2eydeli&s=6  )

Comment: Post your adapter code, it may be something in there.  Also check your data... If it's working elsewhere but not for this one contact, it's quite possible you saved the info to the wrong type when you created this contact (or so it seems to me).

Comment: I edit the code and paste it.check it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your loops... you only have one variable for each item and you are re-setting it each time through.

When you go to create the strings to add to your listview, you only have the value from the last iteration through each of your loops.

You should move the bulk of the string creation into those loops.

Start the string outside the loop, setting the contact name, and then add the phone numbers (and type) on each iteration through the phone # loop, then add the e-mails (and type) to the string on each iteration through the e-mail loop.

**EDIT**

I think this is what you want:

```
private void readContacts() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        displayName = "";

        displayName = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String holder = "";
        holder = holder + displayName;

        /* Phone Number and Type */

        if (Integer
                .parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                contactPhoneType = pCur
                        .getInt(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

                switch (contactPhoneType) {
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                    holder = holder + ", Home";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                    holder = holder + ", Work";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    holder = holder + ", Mobile";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                    holder = holder + ", Other";
                    break;
                }
                holder = holder
                        + ", "
                        + (pCur.getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
            }
            pCur.close();
        }

        /* Email */
        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null, Email.CONTACT_ID
                + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) {
            int contactPhoneType = emails
                    .getInt(emails
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
            switch (contactPhoneType) {
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME:
                holder = holder + ", Home";
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK:
                holder = holder + ", Work";
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_MOBILE:
                holder = holder + ", Mobile";
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_OTHER:
                holder = holder + ", Other";
                break;
            }
            holder = holder
                    + ", "
                    + (emails
                            .getString(emails
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        }
        emails.close();
        contactlist.add(holder);
    }
    Collections.sort(contactlist);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Check the above comment I paste in my section and also check the image link you got the idea.I did atmost all type of editings but no use.you need full coding ?

Comment: Help me I didn't get the answer

Comment: Barak you got the answer, I didn't get the answer, Let me know where is the actual problem ?

Comment: With your full code it was easy to find the issue.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for keep contact with me to do this work, you are atmost 95 % OK. The small problem is when I Save 2 number and 2 Email to a particular contact, the display will be like ( http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=m93s6a&s=6  ), but your code give me the display like this (  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2nm0pw6&s=6  ), Your code is some thing different from my code, so I am trying to edit your code to get the display as I need, if you have time it is very easy to you to edit your own code than me. once again Thanks.